# jekyll error reading configuration,and show nothing on web,my system is win7

Tags: configuration, jekyll

**When i execute "jekyll server --safe -- watch" on cmd, i have this WARNING:**

WARNING: Error reading configuration. Using default .
Configuration file: `<INVALID>` D:/git/blog/_config.yml

**And my html source files is:**

/git/blog/index.html:

```
---

layout: default

---
Hello jekyll
```

and /git/blog/_layouts/default.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>My blog</title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

but i get nothing on web page, except the title "My blog",
Is someone had met this before???

Comment: The warning is talking about `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't see the content `Hello jekyll` from your HTML source file unless you add the Liquid tag `{{ content }}` somewhere in your layout file. This is where the content from your pages will be displayed.

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>My blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>{{ content }}</body>
</html>
```

---

Plus, your [config file](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) seems to be missing, like David Jacquel already said in his comment.
This isn't necessarily a bad thing, it's just that Jekyll will use the [default configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#default-configuration) when no config file is present.

But the missing config file doesn't have anything to do with the fact that your web page isn't showing anything - that's because of the missing `{{ content }}` tag, like I said in the beginning!